# How to make a python dataclass field not allow None values

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

After learning a little about dataclasses, it seems that a dataclass will always HAVE all the properties you defined. Adding the `Optional` only means that you don't have to pass a param into the constructor. I want to make a field required in the sense that it cannot be `None`.

So if I have

```
@dataclass
class SomeClass():
  a: int
  b: Optional[int] = None

test = SomeClass(a=None)
```

I want this to throw an error, but don't know the best way to achieve that result.

Two ideas I have are using the `__post_init__` to run validation logic or maybe using pydantic.

Is there a generally accepted solution for this problem?

Comment: Unless you are using an interpreter/compiler that enforces types, python will not do that for you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Isn't None just a value? meaning you can run validation on it at runtime?

Comment: @ClayCasper, yes, you can ensure it with `__post_init__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways you mentioned are quite suitable, but [`pydantic.dataclasses`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/dataclasses/) will do automatic validation for you:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass as pdataclass

@pdataclass
class SomeClass():
  a: int
  b: Optional[int] = None

test = SomeClass(a=None)
```

---

Gives a verbose output/error:

```
    test = SomeClass(a=None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_dataclasses.py", line 132, in __init__
    s.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(ArgsKwargs(args, kwargs), self_instance=s)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for SomeClass
a
  Input should be a valid integer [type=int_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
```

---

With standard `dataclasses` you'd need to provide your own validation logic within `__post_init__` method:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class SomeClass():
  a: int
  b: Optional[int] = None

  def __post_init__(self):
      if not isinstance(self.a, int):
          raise ValueError('Field `a` must be of integer type')

test = SomeClass(a=None)
```

---

```
    test = SomeClass(a=None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 5, in __init__
..., in __post_init__
    raise ValueError('Field `a` must be of integer type')
ValueError: Field `a` must be of integer type
```

Comment: Would just checking `if a is None` not be enough?

Comment: @ClayCasper, you may do so, but it will not ensure a real type checking for field `a: int`. Like `SomeClass(a=['a'])` would be admitted by  `if a is None:`, while the passed argument is way far from integer.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!